# How to make a power quality analyzer/meter?

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, power-electronics, power-quality

I want to make a device (like Fluke 434/435) to get the electrical power supply's:-

1. Total harmonic distortions.
2. Amplitude of different harmonics.

My aim is to measure the quality of the power supply coming to my industrial grade 3 phase motor. Basically, I need real-time monitoring of AC current and voltage of the supply, but I am a bit unsure if current sensors like the ACS712 will work.

Please advise if the current waveform given by the ACS7112 can give the harmonics.

PS: I am not seeking a recommendation for any product.

Comment: The data sheet fully specifies the operating bandwidth.

Comment: bandejiya - Hi, Please do *not* delete a [question](/questions/574997) and re-post an edited version again. Although in this case you only deleted 2 comments when you deleted your previous question, you still deleted work by other people. As explained in the help center regarding [closed questions](/help/closed-questions), after you edited your previous question to remove the "shopping" part, you needed to wait for it to be reviewed and consider re-opening it. You bypassed that by deleting and re-posting it. As I said, please don't do that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific power monitoring ics that might suit your requirements better. There are plenty of examples using Arduinos on the interwebs.

Whilst you could use an ACS712, these devices have a significant noise floor vs a Rogowski coil or current transformer.
You might want to consider the accuracy and how many harmonics you require. You pay for performance when you buy the likes of Fluke for good reason.